# How to determine the module system from a node js library code for importing config file

Tags: node.js, commonjs, esmodules

I'm working on adding support for `.js` config file in a NodeJS library. NodeJS support two module system - *[ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) & [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html)* - and since javascript files with `.js` can be treated as an ES Module or a Common JS module based on the what is defined as type parameter in `package.json`, I'm not able to figure out, how to know that what module system is a user of the library is using. Based on the module system used by the user only I can decide whether to import config using `require()` or `import()`

Comment: based on [this](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/packages.html#packagejson-and-file-extensions), I think you just need to add `type: "commonjs"` so both `commonjs` & `module` users can use your library.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way too know about the module type of the application code form a node module. One workaround that I can think of would be using something like [parent-package-json](https://github.com/maxrimue/parent-package-json) –

```js
import getParent from 'parent-package-json';
const parent = getParent();
 
const parentModuleType = parent ? parent.type : DEFAULT_MODULE_TYPE;
```